# Trigger sidebar expansion Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way of triggering the sidebar expansion via shortcut or any command on the command pallete on Sublime text 3? This is a missing function for me. Having to use the mouse to resize it to the maximum it's really frustrating due the fact that ST3 have a lot of shortcuts for avoiding the mouse use.

Something like: Toggling between a default size and the expanded size would be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to resize the sidebar using the keyboard. However:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> will show/hide the sidebar.
- *Double-clicking* the sidebar divider will automatically resize the sidebar to its maximum size (i.e. the size required to be able to read the longest filename in it without the need to scroll).

Comment: I know about these shortcuts, they're useful, but it still requires the mouse use... =/